# How do you create a dropdown answer in android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for something similar to a drop down menu but when you click on it a block of text drops instead of a list of clickable items. Then you should be able to click to close it again when finished. My app is an informational app so, I want to make a list of several of these within a glossary in my app.

Any ideas??

Comment: check if this is helpful https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: can you accept it ?

Comment: I would but I don't know how to accept a comment. Also, if anyone is interested I found this link to be clearer: https://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/android-tips-expandablecollapsible-views/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `Spinner` in android:

Here is the example :

```
Spinner mSipnner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin_beneficiary_targetcode);

List<String> categories2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories2.add("Choose code");
    categories2.add("001");
    categories2.add("002");
    categories2.add("003");
    categories2.add("004");
    categories2.add("005");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories2);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        ////Spinner item selected
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String targetCode_item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            // Showing selected spinner item
            //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + category_item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    mSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```